# Amazon Seller Central Selenium dropdown select error using Python

Tags: python, selenium, amazonsellercentral

I have been trying to automate Amazon Seller Central's storage report download. I have tried to use the select function for other dropdown options. Here is what I coded for other dropdown menus and worked:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('downloadDateDropdown'))

select.select_by_value('0')
```

However, when I tried this method on another dropdown which has a different shape and design, I keep getting a message that python cannot find the element.

The following is the code from Seller Central that I have been trying to figure out automating using Selenium:
[Code from Seller Central](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObA2H.png)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

IN the html you attached there is not attribute id with value 'downloadDateDropdown'

Also there are no select tag in the html , you can use select class with select tags . FOr other tags use normal click

1. CLick Dropdown menu to view the list
2. Click the displayed option

Code would be :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//xpathofdropdownmenu"))
).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//xpathofoption"))
).click()
```